# C++ Executable sizes increases depending on a macro definition

Tags: c++11, macros

So I have the following class:

```
#define SINGLETON Singleton::GetInstance()

//#define MY_MACRO(X) Singleton::RunS(X) 
//#define MY_MACRO(X) SINGLETON->Run(X)

class Singleton;
using Singleton_ptr = std::shared_ptr < Singleton > ;

class Singleton
{
public:

    static Singleton_ptr GetInstance();
    static wstring  RunS(__in const wstring& strSource) { return SINGLETON->Run(strSource); }

public:

    void Run(__in const wstring& strSource);

private:

    static Singleton_ptr ms_Instance;
    Singleton();
};
```

You can see that the I have two different ways of defining `MY_MACRO`.

1. `#define MY_MACRO(X) Singleton::RunS(X)`. AKA - **def1**
2. `#define MY_MACRO(X) SINGLETON->Run(X)`. AKA - **def2**

`MY_MACRO` macro is used ~2000 times in my entire solution.

It appears that the way I'm defining `MY_MACRO` has a significant impact on my executable sizes.
**def2** generate much bigger executables (increase by 120KB) then **def1**.

#### Questions

1. Can anyone explain why this simple difference in the macro definition change the excusable sizes?
2. Is there an optimal way of defining `MY_MACRO` to minimize executables sizes?

Comment: 60 bytes / occurrence ? that's not much. is this an optimized build?

Comment: Yes. optimized code to minimize size. Either way, compiling the code was identical in both cases. the only difference was the macro definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `def2` macro definition the compiler will add code to create and destroy a `std::shared_ptr < Singleton >` at each macro call site. With `def1` the `std::shared_ptr < Singleton >` is created/destroyed only in the `Singleton::RunS()` function code.

I kind of doubt that that would account for the entire size difference, so I suspect that there might be other causes for the increased amount of code.  For example, if you're compiling with GCC and including symbols, the debugging information is included in the executable and the additional function calls in `def2` might account for some additional debugging information being added to the binary.

Comment: That is a nice explanation. Regarding whether this _would account for the entire size difference_, well, I compiled once with `def1` and then again with `def2` and saw the size difference.